# Jmeter displays doubled results in html report and aggregate report when running in non gui mode

Tags: jmeter

I have a Test plan which when I run in the Gui Mode execute the sampler one time, but when I start the Test Plan from the command line I get the sampler to be running twice.

I have deleted the result.jtl file to insure that the results are not accumulated.
Non gui command:

jmeter -n -t C:\Users\cthakor\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\bin\examples\Script.jmx -l C:\Users\cthakor\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\bin\examples\result.jtl

jmeter -g C:\Users\cthakor\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\bin\examples\result.jtl -o C:\Users\cthakor\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\bin\examples\HTMLReport

[Test plan image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4R5mG.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what's wrong without seeing the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) contents

It might be the case you're getting an extra result due to [redirection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) or to retrieval of the [embedded resource](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses)

So most probably the dashboard contains correct number of requests, and in GUI the sub-result is being merged into the main sample result.

If this is not something you want to see in the dashboard you can add the next line to user.properties file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false
```

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)